# Strong passwords vs ransomware for Linux login

Tags: linux, password, malware

Let's assume I have connected a Linux computer to my local network. There is one login to this computer with a strong password that only I know.

1. Can ransomware that has infiltrated my network (via another computer) gain access to the data on the Linux computer?
2. Can the ransomware change data on the Linux computer?

I read that ransomware is good at steeling credentials.

Comment: If your password is ever input or saved on the infected device, sure, why not?

Comment: I mean the situation where the ransomware does not know the password, i.e. not in this way either.

Comment: does the password get typed in on the machine that is infected, or similar?

Comment: No, we assume that the Linux machine is not infected and only there the password gets typed.

Comment: That you are concerned about the risk of ransomware implies the machine holds data of value, but you told us nothing about how this data is accessed. Even with all the facts, there is no yes/no answer here. Cyber security is about reducing and mitigating risks. There is no "fix".

Comment: The data is only viewed via one normal Linux textmode login using the strong password. My main concern is about ransomeware changing/deleting my data.

Comment: Linux only stores the password as hash in /etc/passwd. So a malware needs to log the password (keylogger) or crack the hash. To prevent ransomeware create a backup and don't store files at all which can be used for blackmail.

Answer (score 2):

Ransomware isn't magic. It is delivered either by someone giving it the necessary permissions to run on the local machine OR by means of a network security exploit that has not yet been patched.

In your situation if you have a user account password that you believe is sufficiently strong, and there is no other way to log on to the system (root account disabled, web server locked down, no remote access to your data through network shares, etc.) then it's not likely that ransomware will be able to access your data on that system.

The remaining access route is via a "zero day" or some other unpatched exploit. The only way to guard against loss or damage of your data against these kind of exploits is with backups, and there is little protection against data theft.

Comment: Ransomware is mostly executed by the user himself through malware or unpatched software, or more unlikely zeroday vulnerabilities of software on the system. No need for open services or other means of login.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation :)

Comment: @pLumo That's a bold claim to make without some hard evidence to back it up. Even if true the definition of "most" needs to be quantified separately as: attack frequency, success rate, and cumulative damage. On the face your claim seems a dubious since there have been many major ransomware attacks that have caught server-side data and so is not easily explainable as social engineering. It's not like sys-admins typically check their email using their server admin account. It's also hard to explain cases of 70-80% of staff machines getting taken out by social engineering. IE **both** are a risk!

Comment: For servers yes, but that is rarely an issue for personal computers without open services. Social engineering is exactly what I mean. The user opens malware documents etc.

Comment: @PhilipCouling How did they catch the server-side data (without social engineering) ?

Comment: @pLumo again, thats a very bold claim. Heartblead, Spectre, Meltdown, ... didn't just affect servers; Heartblead affected any SSL server port, and Spectre/Meltdown was any remote password login AFAIK. It's not just servers that have those but home machines. Again I say, be careful about down-playing the risk of pure service attack without hard evidence that it's not an issue.

Comment: @fkarger Heartblead, Spectre, Mealtdown are all exploits that don't require social engineering (those are the ones that stick in my memory, but not the whole list). Server side there's also [SQL injection attacks](https://xkcd.com/327/) which easily allow access to a lot of data without any social exploit. [XSS attacks](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/xss/) are not **necessarily** the user's fault.

Answer (score 2):

As other's have pointed out there's no way to say "you are safe".  Even if you might be.

### Without Social Engineering

Machines can be vulnrable to exploits. Older examples include [Heartblead](https://heartbleed.com/), [Spectre, and Mealtdown](https://meltdownattack.com/).  Which can be used to attack a system without user interaction.  Heartblead in particular was capable of extracting data from a system without even logging in.  This should scare anyone who understands how much security experts managed to extract with it.

More generically, if the machine has external services such as webapps or just APIs etc., then there's always a risk those apps contain exploits such as [SQL Injection attacks](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection) or [XSS Attacks](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/xss/).

### With social engineering

Once a corporate network has been compromised there's also a greatly increased risk of social engineering, such as sending Phishing emails directly from legitimate email accounts beloinging to staff members who have already been compromised.

For this reason, every company I've worked for in recent years has had a "Phishing report" and "Security risk" channel to report problems as soon as we become aware of them. At least that way a user can report they've been compromised and alert others not to trust their communications while the issue is resolvled.

### Passwords are not Strong

You've specifically mentioned "Strong passwords" in your question.  Modern security advice does not treat passwords as strong any more.  Even if they are [cryptographically secure](https://xkcd.com/936/), password re-use, password sharing, and [Phishing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phishing) / [Whaling](https://www.ncsc.gov.uk/guidance/whaling-how-it-works-and-what-your-organisation-can-do-about-it) remain serious concerns.

If your network is already compromised, then there's an increased risk that this can be used to spoof the machine in question in order to perform a man in the middle attack.  Passwords fall right into this trap.  Unlike private keys, you give the actual secret to the server, so a man in the middle can copy your password and keep it.

Modern advice would only use passwords as one part of multi-factor authentication so that a compromised password is not enough to gain access.  Private keys, and certificates, smart-cards are all good ways to either suppliment passwords or abandon password based access altogether.

Answer (score 0):

If you use anything from outside the computer, the only possible answer is:

### Yes

Malware can possibly infiltrate your computer via network through vulnerable services but that is not the only possibility. Strong passwords is a necessity but by far not sufficient.

Mostly, malware (e.g. ransomware) is executed by the user themself and does not need to steal credentials at all.

If you *use* your computer, there is always a risk that there is software which has vulnerabilities that has not been fixed yet, because

- it's a zero day vulnerability (see lately the rar or libwebp vulnerabilities)
- your distro does not serve patches fast enough or is not maintained anymore
- you haven't installed the patches yet

Mitigation strategies:

- Keep all (!!) software up to date at all (!!) times
- Do not open files from unknown/unsafe sources

  - or use containers or a VM to do so
- Do not attach potentially unknown/unsafe devices
- Only use software that is well-tested and well-maintained and trusted company or a good community.
- Harden the computer

  - use a Firewall and block any (at least incoming) connection that you don't need
  - use strong passwords
  - deny root and password login via ssh
- Keep data away from the scope of the user
- Have a backup ready

Comment: Thank you! Let's assume that the Linux computer is only used, for example, to enter presumably secure commands such as ls in the command line to get to know Linux. Do you still see attacking possibilities for the ransomware other than those already described?

Comment: Unlikely, but possible for sure. I would have considered `rar` a secure command before. Maybe `ls` has a currently unknown zero-day bug and allows code executions with some specially crafted file names. Unlikely, but who knows.

Comment: Specifically, because of ransomware, you should ensure backups are time-locked. If the user has access to delete backups then so does the ransomware.  In older days this meant cycling server hard drives or tapes into a vault, but more modern cloud solutions also exist.

Comment: @pLumo Ok, I understand. That means theoretically yes, but probably no.

Comment: @PhilipCouling Yes, offline backups make a lot of sense.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Can ransomware that has infiltrated my network (via another computer) gain access to the data on the Linux computer?

Yes, absolutely. Computers in LANs already benefit of an easier access than computers in different networks, which can be protected by perimetral firewalls, etc. The ransomware may infect your computer depending on how the latter is protected (patches installed, local firewall filtering connections, etc.) Having a ransomware in a LAN is a very bad thing as this means the malware has already breached some defenses.

> 2. Can the ransomware change data on the Linux computer?

Yes, absolutely. They usually encrypt data with a secret key which is disclosed to you only after you pay a ransom. But there's nothing preventing a ransomware/malware to change anything else in your computer.